# Bootstrap 4 - how to colspan and rowspan

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-tables

I have this bootstrap 4 table which behaves not as I expect

Or maybe I have misinterpreted the meaning of bootstrap 4 tables tags

Can you kindly hint what is wrong?

here it is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1uokLh67/11/

e.g. as you can see, they **Pay To** and **Customer** cells are not spanning 50% each one but there is some empty space at the end and you'll see others behaviors

Thank you

```html
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <caption>A complex table</caption>
       
       
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th class="col-4">Invoice #123456789</th>
         <th class="col-2">Date:</th>
         <th class="col-6">14 January 2025</th>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td class="col-6">
           <strong>Pay to:</strong><br>
           Acme Billing Co.<br>
           123 Main St.<br>
           Cityville, NA 12345
          </td>
          <td class="col-6">
           <strong>Customer:</strong><br>
           John Smith<br>
           321 Willow Way<br>
           Southeast Northwestershire, MA 54321
          </td>
         </tr>
       </thead>
         
         
       <tbody>
         <tr>
              <th class="col-3">Qty.</th>      
              <th class="col-3">Name / Description</th>
              <th class="col-3">Price</th>
              <th class="col-3">Cost</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
                <td class="col-3">1000</td>
                <td class="col-3">Paperclips</td>      
                <td class="col-3">0.01</td>
                <td class="col-3">10.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td class="col-3">100</td>      
          <td class="col-3">Staples (box)</td>
          <td class="col-3">1.00</td>
          <td class="col-3">100.00</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>   
         <tr>
              <td  class="col-3"></td>
              <td class="col-3"></td>
              <th class="col-3">Subtotal</th>
              <td class="col-3"> 110.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td class="col-3"></td>
              <th class="col-3">Tax</th>
              <td class="col-3"> 8% </td>
              <td class="col-3">8.80</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td class="col-3"></td>
              <td class="col-3"></td>
              <th class="col-3">Grand Total</th>
              <td class="col-3">$ 118.80</td>
         </tr>
       </tfoot>
         
      </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `colspan` to resolve your problem...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <caption>A complex table</caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-4">Invoice #123456789</th>
        <th class="col-2">Date:</th>
        <th class="col-6" colspan="2">14 January 2025</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-6" colspan="1">
          <strong>Pay to:</strong>
          <br>
          Acme Billing Co.<br>
          123 Main St.<br>
          Cityville, NA 12345
        </td>
        <td class="col-6" colspan="3">
          <strong>Customer:</strong>
          <br>
          John Smith<br>
          321 Willow Way<br>
          Southeast Northwestershire, MA 54321
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-3">Qty.</th>
        <th class="col-3">Name / Description</th>
        <th class="col-3">Price</th>
        <th class="col-3">Cost</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-3">1000</td>
        <td class="col-3">Paperclips</td>
        <td class="col-3">0.01</td>
        <td class="col-3">10.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-3">100</td>
        <td class="col-3">Staples (box)</td>
        <td class="col-3">1.00</td>
        <td class="col-3">100.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-3"></td>
        <td class="col-3"></td>
        <th class="col-3">Subtotal</th>
        <td class="col-3"> 110.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-3"></td>
        <th class="col-3">Tax</th>
        <td class="col-3"> 8% </td>
        <td class="col-3">8.80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-3"></td>
        <td class="col-3"></td>
        <th class="col-3">Grand Total</th>
        <td class="col-3">$ 118.80</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I got it, the bootstrap tags mislead me, I thought the tag was supposed to do the job. This is the solution but IMPO this makes the bootstrap tags to loose some sense.